# installed ruby-debug, now getting 'application starting in bugger on ...'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed ruby-debug, when I do:

rails server -debugger

I get:

```
Rails 3.0.1 application starting in bugger on ....
```

Why does it say bugger?

Then after that line, I get back to the command prompt so it just stops for some reason?

Going to a page shows:

```
bugger database is not configured
```

Then if I try and do:

```
rails server
```

It fails to start:

```
2010-11-22 00:42:31] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2010-11-22 00:42:31] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16) [i686-darwin10.4.0]
[2010-11-22 00:42:31] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
Exiting
... address already in use
```

How can I kill the process, not sure how to filter for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want activate the debugger when you launch rails server you need use the option -u

```
rails -u server
```

it's explain on help information :

```
[shingara@maison ]  master  %
 rails server -h                       
 22/11/10 09:34:49 Usage: rails server
 [mongrel, thin, etc] [options]
     -p, --port=port                  Runs Rails on the specified port.
                                      Default: 3000
     -b, --binding=ip                 Binds Rails to the specified ip.
                                      Default: 0.0.0.0
     -c, --config=file                Use custom rackup configuration file
     -d, --daemon                     Make server run as a Daemon.
     -u, --debugger                   Enable ruby-debugging for the server.
     -e, --environment=name           Specifies the environment to run this
 server under
 (test/development/production).
                                      Default: development
     -P, --pid=pid                    Specifies the PID file.
                                      Default: tmp/pids/server.pid

     -h, --help                       Show this help message.
```